# how we navigate through web pages will maintaining the navbar from the main landing page

Tags: html

I have two html files; index.html and registrationform.html.

index is the main form having the website navbar that I want fixed at the top as I move to registrationform page or any other page.

how do I go about it in html?

Comment: A variety of ways.  Both pages can have the same common structure, you can use frames (a pretty old and often frowned upon approach, but it can work), the site can be a single-page-application and navigating simply updates certain sections of the page to different content.  What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the css with `position: fixed;` the top bar will be reloaded for each page but will stay at the same position.

If you do want to load this top bar only on the first load, you can use ajax to only reload the main content of the page or in a more modern using a JS framework like Vue or React to build a Single Page Application (SPA).